# Can I apply different transformations to each side of this inequality?

Tags: inequality, arithmetic, first-order-logic

Does the following hold for natural numbers:

$\forall x :  \mathbb{N} , \forall y :  \mathbb{N} \bullet  (x < (y+1)^2) \Rightarrow  ((x+1) < (y + 1 +1)^2)$   (**1**)

If (**1**) is valid I would like I to use it in a proof.

Is there some general theorem that states what transformations or functions can be applied to either side of an inequality?

Comment: On the right of (2) why the parens around the thing after < ? they don't do anything. So do you mean $suc([(suc)y]^2)$?

Comment: @coffeemath Hopefully, it is OK now.

Comment: Stilt not clear what is being squared on right of (2). Could you write (2) out using $u+1$ instead of suc(u)?

Comment: @coffeemath  I have simplified the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually there doesn't exist such a theorem. it's because there are infinitely many transformations we can apply.

you can show easily in your case that the statement holds for every  value of $x$ and $y$ in $\mathbb{N}$, namely:

Let $(1)$ be:

$$ x < (y+1)^2 $$

Let $(2)$ be:

$$ (x + 1) < (y + 2)^2 $$

If you apply $(2) - (1)$, you conclude that the statement holds for every $y$ greater than $-1$.

So the translation by $+1$ holds for every value in Natural Numbers. But there is no generalization. The most close would be the archimedean property of integers, if you had a linear expression.

But you need to precise the function between $x$ and $y$. not all translation by $1$ on $x$ gives you equivalent translation on $y$. here you lack of arguments.